# Imposing Restrictions on the installation of apk

Tags: android

I want to make certain restrictions on distribution of the Android mobile application(apk).

I am currently not uploading the apk to Android market.

I want to provide the apk to the user with the following restrictions.

i> After the Android mobile application(apk) is installed , the application should work for only 5 days.

ii> The apk file cant be reinstalled on the same mobile device more than once.

Is there any way using code by which , I can make the above restrictions?

Kindly provide your suggestions/hints for implementing the same.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that you store on the device itself will be removed once the app is uninstalled, so you cannot check for a previous installation. You could hide something away on the SD card, you then cannot legislate for the user wiping their SD card, or swapping SD cards.

I would suggest registering a [unique ID](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) for the app installation with a simple web service. You can then interrogate this web service periodically to determine whether the 5 day limit has expired. Even if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, 5 day restriction will still be applied.

Comment: I am thinking of creating a private key ,where I will specify the validity of the key till the next 5 days . If the user tries to install the application after 5 days , then it should not install .

Comment: Where are you generating this key? If it's in your app, then you can't reliably persist it on the device to prevent somebody from uninstalling then reinstalling the app to get a new 5 day trial. If you're generating it on a server, I'm not sure that you need that complexity. Simply call a web service with your unique ID, and the web service can manage al of the logic and simply return a boolean to indicate whether the app is authorised to run. Do this in an HTTPS transaction, and you're well protected.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply . Currently , its not possible to setup a server & the mobile application I have developed is a standalone app. So , while signing our application, we are using a private key . I am thinking of putting the validity period for 5 days from the day I am generating the private key.Need to checkout practically after creating the private key.

Comment: Presumably you're only releasing a small number of instances. If that's the case, why not just embed an asset containing the expiry timestamp before you sign the app? It's tamper-proof. You read it at runtime to decide whether to execute or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be an API which provides you the date when the apk is installed on the device, later we can compare that installation date to the current date and calculate if 5 days have occured or not. this may solve the problem. Sorry but I'm not aware of any such API's to get the installation date, but if the API is found then your problem can be solved. I just suggested a method of doing it. Let me also know if it has worked.